# Search text in column A for dict key, if found then set column B to dict value in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

Given a dataframe and a dict like the following:

```
Col A             Col B  
f3s34Roger         nan  
bll23Dawn          nan  
Misty3r2w          nan  
efJunea4l          nan  

vendor_dict = {'Roger': 'cups','Charlie':'plates','Misty':'bowls'}
```

I want to search each row to see if Col 'A' contains a key in the dict. If it does, I want to set Col 'B' to be the key's value.

Testing with just a static value, this works:

```
df['Col B'] = np.where(df['Col A'].str.find('Roger'),'', 'cups')
```

But that doesn't give me the dict mapping. I've tried:

```
df['Col B'] = np.where(df['Col A'].str.find().map(vendors)
```

but that's not correct. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str.findall` then use `map`

```
df['Col B']=df['Col A'].str.findall('|'.join(vendor_dict.keys())).str[0].map(vendor_dict)
0     cups
1      NaN
2    bowls
3      NaN
Name: ColA, dtype: object
```

Comment: Brilliant YOBEN_S! I would have never come up with that. Thank you so much for the help!